# Use a string with special characters in a node machine definition

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'm new to SailsJS and I'm trying to understand how to make everything work as it should ! :)

The last problem I can't seem to figure out is how to define some endpoints for a special endpoint.

I am setting up a Messenger bot webhook. To verify the webhook, Facebook sends a GET request to my URL with the parameters `hub.mode`, `hub.verify_token` and `hub.challenge` which, as you can see, contain a `.` in their names.

And because of this point I do not know how to define these parameters in my action definition:

```
module.exports = {


  friendlyName: 'Webhook check',


  description: 'Action to return succes on GET call of webhook URL',


  inputs: {
      hub: {
        type: 'ref'
      }
  },


  exits: {
    success: {
      responseType: ''
    },
    notValidated: {
      statusCode: 403
    }
  },


  fn: async function (inputs, exits) {
    console.log(this.req.param('hub.mode'));
    console.log(this.req.allParams())
    if (inputs.hub_mode === 'subscribe' && inputs.hub_verify_token === sails.config.facebook.verifyToken) {
      return exits.success(inputs.hub_challenge);
    } else {
      return exits.notValidated();
    }
  }


};
```

I can still access the parameters using the direct access to the Express req object (`this.req.param('hub.mode')` for example) but this can't be the right way to go as it breaks the idea of the node machine specification that puts emphasis on the definition of the function.

Does anyone have an idea on how to combine machine-as-action syntax and parameters such as those chosen by Facebook ?

Thanks by advance :)

Comment: There's some relevant documentation on [Sails machine-as-action syntax](https://github.com/sailshq/machine-as-action) & [Sails actions and controllers](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/actions-and-controllers) explaining the process further. Facebook explains some of the concepts behind their [URL parameters here](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/1016122818401732). Hope this helps and best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I had already read those links and came to SO because I didn't find there what I was looking for.
It even never talks about the restrictions put on the names of the inputs and exits parameters. Which is why I wanted to know if someone with better experience with SailsJS or the machine syntax could help me.
About Facebook parameters, in my case they aren't parameters I have chosen or can change either. I'm stuck with my workaround but it just doesn't seem to be the correct way ! :D

Comment: Have you tried  `'hub.mode': {` Instead of `hub: {` ?

Comment: Yes I tried with 'hub.mode', 'hub\.mode' and hub:{ mode: {}} and all fail sadly. I am going to ask the question in the node-machine Google group to see if I can get an insight or a definitive negative answer. 
The specification (http://node-machine.org/spec/machine#inputKey) doesn't seem to leave me much hope but it seems to me as a huge limitation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed with Mike McNeil on the node-machine Google group, it is actually not possible to map parameters of this style in the node-machine specification.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/node-machine/uQ3BdNR149I

Nonetheless, Mike McNeil created a Trello card to see how to integrate this use-case in the machine-as-action link to the SailsJs framework.